# How to move commits on top of master if HEAD is detached?

Tags: git, git-branch

sorry, noob here.

I've researched this, but everyone refers to branches and I'm not sure I'm dealing with a branch.

A while ago I messed up the website I'm working on over the process of 4 commits. So I went back four commits, and just kept working from there. Since then I've saved maybe 10 commits, but I never "officially" made a branch, so I'm not sure if I'm on a branch. I'm definitely not on MASTER because I left it a long time ago.

How do I make what I'm working on into the MASTER branch?

**added per request**:

```
$ git branch -v 
* (detached from 626a6f1) aea944b trying to make new branch 
  bottom_drop_side_menu 46e7358 quick save 
  lowermenu 4e89d92 So here's a kind of nice lower menu. Client doesn't dig :( 
  master 2071f52 the categories arent working...
```

Comment: @cbolorinos Please try running `git branch -v` and show us the output.

Comment: `$ git branch -v
 

*(detached from 626a6f1) aea944b trying to make new branch
  

bottom_drop_side_menu   46e7358 quick save
  

lowermenu               4e89d92 So here's a kind of nice lower menu. Client doesn't dig :(
  

master                  2071f52 the categories arent working...`

Answer (score 2):

Simply make a new branch where you are (on the detached HEAD aea944b):

```
git checkout -b tmp
```

And replay it on `master`:

```
git rebase master
```

Then merge tmp in master

```
git checkout master
git merge tmp
```

See also "[Why did my Git repo enter a detached HEAD state?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3965714/6309)".

Answer (score 0):

you are in '**detached head**' state. one option would be to *stash* the changes you have right now and apply them to **master**.

```
git stash
git checkout master
git apply
```

you might have merge conflicts to solve between the state you are on now and the current state of **master**.

Comment: Wouldn't you lose the history of commits done in the detached HEAD branch though?

Comment: good point  ... yes, that's true ... the commits would be squashed. but if that is ok it's really quick and simple.